# With Kotlin delegate, have reference of the parent "this" object when creating the delegate object

Tags: kotlin

I would like to use Delegation on my Kotlin project, but I have a peculiar requirement. The delegation object itself should hold a reference to the parent object. To give you an example let's consider the following code:

```kotlin
interface MyInterface

class MyImpl(val a: MyTest?) : MyInterface

class MyTest : MyInterface by MyImpl(null)
```

What I'd like to do is replace `null` above with a `this` reference to `MyTest` object. But compiler doesn't let me with the error

```tex
'this' is not defined in this context
```

When I decompile the produced code, I get something like

```java
public final class MyTest implements MyInterface
{
    private final /* synthetic */ MyImpl $$delegate_0;
    
    public MyTest() {
        this.$$delegate_0 = new MyImpl(null);
    }
}
```

which would seem perfectly legal, if I wanted to pass `this` instead of `null` when the delegate is initialized. But I can't figure how to do it. Is it a Kotlin's restriction or am I doing something wrong?

I know that I can bypass this restriction by using a var inside MyImpl and give a reference to `parent.this` at later time on my code. But this would mean that MyImpl will have a mutable reference of something that could be `val` instead, and I don't think this solution is elegant enough.

Comment: You basically require that at the time `MyImpl` is being constructed `MyTest` already exists and at the time `MyTest` is being constructed `MyImpl` exists. I believe this is not possible and not only in Kotlin/Java. You need to make at least one side `var` and I think `lateinit` makes sense here.

Comment: I don't think this is the case. This would be try if I used the syntax `class MyTest (b : MyImpl(this)) : MyInterface by b`. But I didn't. First `MyImpl` should be initialized and the Delegate, as it is already shown by Java decompiler. So, in my mind, I don't see a contradiction there.

Comment: Hmm... I think you're right and actually it is possible to create such circular references. For some reason Kotlin is very "strict" when it comes to delegates. For example, you can't delegate to a property that was initialized in the constructor. It seems like delegate has to be provided externally, it can't be constructed by the object itself. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Maybe this is because they wanted to avoid problems with NPEs. Passing `this` somewhere during object initialization is one of very few cases when Kotlin may throw NPE. Delegates are critical for functioning of the delegating object, so maybe they wanted to avoid propagating potential problems by making it more strict. I don't know. Your example seems like a something that should be technically doable.

Comment: This is the biggest limitation of Kotlin's class delegation and the main reason why I barely use it.